# How to do data validation

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I need to create a form where they will be 20 choices(time slots) in drop down menu. If a choice is chosen, it should be unable to choose from again.
How can I do this.

Kindly advise, thank you.

Comment: Chosen again in another list item?

Comment: By "form", a default SharePoint add/edit form? Or a custom InfoPath or HTML/JavaScript form?

Answer (score 1):

When you add a column to a list, you can enable the "Unique" option:

[image]

No two list items will be allowed to have the same entered value. Similar to a unique constraint in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

How to prevent multiple selections of the same value in a drop-down in a table for your reference:

https://answers.laserfiche.com/questions/81032/How-to-prevent-multiple-selections-of-the-same-value-in-a-dropdown-in-a-table